# webpack - copy all images from image folder and paste to new destination

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using file loader to take images from css path and paste it to build folder. But that lefts out images that the website needs but they are not in css files.

I want to copy all images in image folder and paste it to the build folder. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to copy static file resources from source to destination directory you could use the [copy webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin)